# c# windows app writing text to file

Tags: c#, windows, file, streamwriter

Having real problems with writing to a text file using following code

```
using HCP1.Common;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.Storage;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

private void imageview_DoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var point = e.GetPosition(imageview);
        var  p1 = (int)point.X;
        var p2 = (int)point.Y;
        string stringVal1;
        string stringVal2;   
        stringVal1 = System.Convert.ToString(p1);
        stringVal2 = System.Convert.ToString(p2);
        Text3.Text = stringVal1;
        Text4.Text = stringVal2;

        if (p2 > 210 && p2 < 235 && p1 > 339 && p1 < 367) { 

            string dave = Environment.NewLine + Text3.Text + "," + Text4.Text;
            string path = @"C:\myfile.txt";
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path);
            string bufferOne = dave;
            sw.Write(bufferOne);
            sw.Close();
            sw.Dispose();
            };
                }
```

When a double tap is done it should save the contents of a textblock to a file but I have three errors

The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.StreamWriter.StreamWriter(System.IO.Stream)' has some invalid arguments (This is at the Streamwriter Line)

cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream' (At the same line)

'System.IO.StreamWriter' does not contain a definition for 'Close' and no extension method 'Close' accepting a first argument of type 'System.IO.StreamWriter' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (This is at the Close line)

As you can see I have SYstem.io reference

Any ideas where im going wrong?

Any help appreciated

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [File.WriteAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx).  It's a static method and does the same as opening, writing and closing a file.  Remember, the less code the less bugs.

```
  if (p2 > 210 && p2 < 235 && p1 > 339 && p1 < 367) 
  { 
        string dave = Environment.NewLine + Text3.Text + "," + Text4.Text;
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\myfile.txt", dave);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks But now it has the error "File does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Add `using System.IO;` to the code. If already there then u have a name clash.  Try `System.IO.File.WriteAllText`

Comment: I have using system.io at the top and it give the same error tried using System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\myfile.txt", dave); and still gives same error

Comment: I did  google for the error and it says I cant use file in a windows store app which is wht i am building is this true if so what do i use to write text to a file?

Comment: Ahh.  My understanding is a Windows store app does not provide access to the underlaying file system.

Comment: so any idea how i can write my text to a file in a windows store app there must be a way surely?

Comment: I think you need to use the `Windows.Storage` namespace.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758325.aspx for more details.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Richard. Windows.storage did the trick